# Calling the correct method for an object, when the object is an instance of a base class

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclassing

I have the following example in Java:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private final String name;
    private final String make;

    public Vehicle(final String name, final String make) {
        this.make = make;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public final class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car(final String name, final String make) {
        super(name, make);
    }
}

public final class Truck extends Vehicle  {
    final Integer grossVehicleWeight;

    public Truck(final String name, final String make, final Integer gvw) {
        super(name, make);
        this.grossVehicleWeight = gvw;
}
```

Say I want to do some work with a vehicle, and the work is not dependent on the subclass of vehicle. So, I have a method in another class like this:

```
public void doStuff(public final Vehicle vehicle) {
    //do stuff here
    //then insert it into my database:
    insertVehicle(vehicle);
}
```

However, I want to do different things in my insertVehicle, so I override that method for each subclass:

```
public void insertVehicle(Car car) { //do stuff for a car }

public void insertVehicle(Truck truck) { //do stuff for a truck }
```

In my doStuff method, I could use instanceOf to determine the class of the vehicle (Car or Truck), and then cast the vehicle into that class and call the insertVehicle method like this:

```
public void doStuff(public final Vehicle vehicle) {
    //do stuff here
    //then insert it into my database:
    if (vehicle instanceof Car) {
        insertVehicle((Car) vehicle);
    } else {
        insertVehicle((truck) vehicle);
    }
}
```

However, I have read that using instanceof is not the best way to do this. [1](https://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html)

How could I best rework this so that I do not have to use instanceof?

Comment: What do these insertVehicle methods do? The OO way to do that is to make insertVehicle (or the specific part of this method) an instance method of Vehicle, overridden in each subclass. Or to use the visitor pattern. Post your code for more concrete help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Visitor Pattern:

```
public interface VehicleVisitor {
    public void visit(Car car);
    public void visit(Truck truck);
}

public class Car extends Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void insert(VehicleVisitor vehicleVisitor) {
        vehicleVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    public void insert(VehicleVisitor vehicleVisitor) {
        vehicleVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public abstract class Vehicle {
    public abstract void insert(VehicleVisitor vehicleVisitor);
}

public class VehicleVisitorImpl implements VehicleVisitor {

    @Override
    public void visit(Car car) {
        System.out.println("insert car");
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Truck truck) {
        System.out.println("insert truck");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Car();
        // finally the agnostic call
        vehicle.insert(new VehicleVisitorImpl());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make the abstract function inside the vehicle for

```
public abstract void doStuff()
```

call this function from the instance of the object that you want to modify

```
ford.doStuff();     //ford is car instance
```

and then you can make modification using this.

```
doStuff()
{
    this.cost += 10;
}
```

Otherwise, you can add a variable for vehicle which indicated what is the vehicle type and return it. Like:

```
  public void doStuff(public final Vehicle vehicle) {
       //do stuff here
       //then insert it into my database:
       if (vehicle.getType()== 'Car') {
            insertVehicle((Car) vehicle);
        } else {
            insertVehicle((truck) vehicle);
        }
   }
```

This variable 'vehicleType' will be in the vehicle class and will be initialized inside the constructor:

```
  public final class Car extends Vehicle {
       public Car(final String name, final String make, final String vehicleType) {
             super(name, make, type);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of problem you trying to solve. If it is persistency make sure you are not reinventing [JPA](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/14/jpa-single-table-inheritance-example/). If it is type-specific processing then you can solve it as @denis suggested. Or if you want to keep entities in POJO-style you can use [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) like:

```
Map<Class<?>, Consumer<Vehicle>> consumers;
{
    consumers.put(Car.class, v -> insertVehicle((Car)v));
    consumers.put(Truck.class, v -> insertVehicle((Truck)v));
}
public void doStuff(public final Vehicle vehicle) {
    //do stuff here
    consumers
      .get(vehicle.getClass())
      .accept(vehicle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have the `insertVehicle()` method abstract in `Vehicle`. And then implement them in the subclasses `Car` and `Truck`.

However, this moves the logic into the POJOs. Maybe it is better to separate db-logic from the POJOs, i.e. just use `instanceof` in this case.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private final String name;
    private final String make;

    public Vehicle(final String name, final String make) {
        this.make = make;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract void insertVehicle();
}

public final class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car(final String name, final String make) {
        super(name, make);
    }

    public void insertVehicle() {

    }
}

public final  class Truck extends Vehicle {
    final Integer grossVehicleWeight;

    public Truck(final String name, final String make, final Integer gvw) {
        super(name, make);
        this.grossVehicleWeight = gvw;
    }

    public void insertVehicle() {

    }
}

public void doStuff(Vehicle vehicle) {
    //do stuff here
    //then insert it into my database:
    vehicle.insertVehicle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like putting `doStuff()` into `Car` and `Truck`, you could have a `doStuff()` method for each of them, and put the common `Vehicle` logic into another method.

```
private void doCommonStuff(final Vehicle vehicle) {
    //do stuff here
}

public void doStuff(final Car car) {
    doCommonStuff(car);
    //then insert it into my database:
    insertVehicle(car);
}

public void doStuff(final Truck truck) {
    doCommonStuff(truck);
    //then insert it into my database:
    insertVehicle(truck);
}
```

We can do better, though, with generics.

```
public abstract class StuffDoer<T extends Vehicle> {
  public void doStuff(final T vehicle) {
    // do stuff here
    // then insert it into my database:
    insertVehicle(vehicle);
  }

  public abstract void insertVehicle(T vehicle);
}

public class CarStuffDoer extends StuffDoer<Car> {
  public void insertVehicle(Car car) {
    // whatever
  }
}

public class TruckStuffDoer extends StuffDoer<Truck> {
  public void insertVehicle(Truck truck) {
    // whatever else
  }
}
```